# Unique ID for HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, logging

Suppose I had a server in the Node environment that served stateless requests via Express. Now suppose I had the need to tag each request's logging with a unique ID as it traverses the sequence of routes and middlewares in my server. Could it be as simple as something like:

In startup code:

```
app.set('count', 0);
```

Later on:

```
let reqId = app.set('count', app.get('count')++);
[snip]
console.log(`${reqId} logging stuff`);
```

etc. (Note, not sure the snippet above actually works) ?

Alternatively is there a library that handles this sort of thing?

Comment: guid is a better idea as an auto increment ID would restart from 0 every time your application restarts

Answer (score 0):

I assign each request a UUID with the first middleware of the stack.  I also output that ID to the response headers, just in case I need to track something down later.

```
const uuid = require('uuid');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  req.id = uuid.v4();
  res.append('X-Request-Id', req.id);

  return next();
};
```

Note: to avoid namespace collisions, you might also consider using a Symbol for your request extensions.  Something like:

```
const EXT = Symbol('REQ_EXT');
req[EXT] = { id: uuid.v4() };
```

Then just be sure to export `EXT` somewhere so that you can use it in other middleware modules.